# Google Play Store/Apple App Store API for app revenue

Tags: python, ios, google-api

Is there any API that allows us to get total revenue that an application in the store earned? If not is there possibility to get a list of subscriptions so I can calculate it on my own?

Comment: Marchello, do you mean ANOTHER app or YOUR app?  If you mean ANOTHER app, there is absolutely no way to get that information.  If you mean your OWN app, all the info is given in the app store back end.

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about my own app. I know that it's possible to get that info by looking into Play Console ( https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6056620?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en in case of Play store) but the question is if it's possible to gather that information using Google API, so I can send HTTP request and get information that I need.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure *this* is exactly what you're after:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/download_sales_and_trends_reports

> "Download sales [...] filtered by your specified criteria."

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I need! Do you know if there is something similar in case of Google Play Store? Is there such and API endpoint?

Comment: @Marchello , I'm afraid I just don't know the current state of affairs for that on good play store, sorry!

Comment: @Fattie hi sir. do you now have any update on the current affairs for this on play store? thank you

Comment: @Marchello did you find similar for Google Play earnings?